# Hotkey switching between spelling dictionaries

Tags: keyboard, spellcheck, spelling

I'm often using 4 languages for writing texts. Now, each time switching languages with:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>
- and changing the language in the popup

Is possible somewhat /applescript, shell-script, anyhow :)/ define a global hotkey for my 4 languages? Something like

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - selects English
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> - selects Czech
- etc..

Ps: and no, the automatic language detection maybe works for few languages, but not for me.. :(

Comment: The app Nisus Writer lets you set that up in its preferences.  But you presumably want it for all apps.

Comment: @TomGewecke yes, looking for how to setup a global hotkey, for the _builtin spellchecker_, e.g. what works for TextEdit, Mail, Safari textboxes (like in this comment), and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [assign shortcuts to scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
    set shown to title of windows contains "Spelling and Grammar"
    if not shown then keystroke ":" using command down
    tell (window 1 where title is "Spelling and Grammar")
        delay 0.1
        tell pop up button 1
            click
            click UI element "Deutsch" of menu 1
        end tell
        if not shown then click button 1
    end tell
end tell
```

It's probably not possible to use the setLanguage: method in NSSpellChecker in DefaultKeyBinding.dict.

Comment: The script ended with error, but got the idea. Thank you :)

Comment: If it was that access for assistive devices is disabled, you can enable it from the accessibility preference pane.